# Variable not found in arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

The error (triggered by selecting the menu item):

> TypeError: org_selected is undefined

is returned for the following snippet:

```
renderItems() {
    let { orgs, org_selected, orgs_loading } = this.props;
    ...
    return <Nav>
        <NavDropdown title={org_login} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            {_.map(orgs, (org) => {
                return <MenuItem
                    key={org.id}
                    onSelect={() => org_selected.set(org.id)}>{org.login}</MenuItem>;
            })}
        </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>;
}
```

Why can't that variable be found: don't arrow functions retain the same scope?

Comment: can you check what in _this.props_? are you sure _org_selected_ exist?

Comment: In the above, it shouldn't matter whether it's an arrow function or a simple function; either way it's a closure over the context in which `org_selected` is defined. Can you do a full [MCVE](/help/mcve), ideally as a Stack Snippet (the `<>` button)?

Comment: @Grundy: You've put your finger on it! If the problem were that there was no `org_selected` variable in scope, it would be a `ReferenceError`, not a `TypeError`. Since it's a `TypeError`, we know you're right, `this.props` either doesn't have `org_selected` or has it but with the value `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, so, seems this can be right guess :-), btw, in Stack Snippet  can be used es6 syntax and jsx?

Comment: @Grundy: I think React (this is React, right?) has a way of letting you specify your code in a script element with a different type, then using the compiler in the browser to handle it. I don't know whether that would also transpile the ES6 to ES5 or if the person viewing the question would have to have a browser whose JavaScript engine supports arrow functions (like V8 in current Chrome).

Comment: @Grundy: I think you can safely paste your comment, perhaps with some details from mine, as an answer. Thanks to the OP quoting the error message (yes!), we know the type of the error, so I don't think it's speculative.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, added, but you feel free edit it or add your own answer with, possibly, more details :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check value for `this.props`. Make sure than in `this.props` exist `org_selected`.

As [T.J. pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268437/variable-not-found-in-arrow-function#comment56278168_34268437), if the problem were that there was no `org_selected` variable in scope, it would be a *ReferenceError*, not a *TypeError*. Since it's a *TypeError*, we know `this.props` either doesn't have an `org_selected` property, or has one with the value `undefined`.